# Local Push Notification not working on iOS, using React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification

I'm having trouble getting my local iOS push notification to work, using React Native. I've checked similar threads but haven't been able to find the answer. This is (meant to be) a basic setup, so hopefully someone can help.

I'm trying to fire the push notification on press of TouchableOpacity objects, wrapped within a FlatList. I'm not getting any code errors, the notification just isn't firing.

I've installed both npm packages as per the documentation, and I'm using React Native v0.65.1: -

```
npm install --save react-native-push-notification
npm i @react-native-community/push-notification-ios --save
```

I've added my code below. There are other files associated to other functionality on the app, but I haven't included them here, as this is the only file which includes code for push notification support.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance...

```
import {Alert, FlatList, Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View} from "react-native";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import GlobalStyle from '../utils/GlobalStyle';
import CustomButton from "../utils/CustomButton";
import SQLite from "react-native-sqlite-storage";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { setAge, setName, increaseAge, getCities } from "../redux/actions";
import PushNotification from "react-native-push-notification";
import PushNotificationIOS from "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios";

// store sqlite open database function
const db = SQLite.openDatabase(
    { name: 'sqlite_db', location: 'default' },
    () => {},
    error => { console.log(error) }
);

export default function Home({ navigation, route }) {

  // replace local state objects with global redux objects
  const { name, age, cities } = useSelector(state => state.userReducer);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // function calls for SQLite and api data fetch
  useEffect(() => {
      getData();
      dispatch(getCities());
  }, []); 

  // fetch data objects from SQLite store
  const getData = () => {
      try {
          db.transaction((tx) => {
              tx.executeSql(
                  'SELECT Name, Age FROM Users',
                  [],
                  (tx, results) => {
                      let length = results.rows.length;
                      if (length > 0) {
                          let userName = results.rows.item(0).Name;
                          let userAge = results.rows.item(0).Age;
                          dispatch(setName(userName));
                          dispatch(setAge(userAge));
                      }
                  }
              )
          })
      } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
      }
  }

  // function to update SQLite data store
  const updateData = async () => {
      if (name.length == 0) {
          Alert.alert('WARNING!', 'Please enter your name')
      } else {
          try {
              db.transaction((tx) => {
                  tx.executeSql(
                      'UPDATE Users SET Name=?',
                      [name],
                      () => {
                          Alert.alert('SUCCESS!', 'Your data has been updated')
                      },
                      error => { console.log(error) }
                  )
              })
          } catch (error) {
              console.log(error)
          }
      }
  }

  // function to remove data from SQLite data store
  const removeData = async () => {
      try {
          db.transaction((tx) => {
              tx.executeSql(
                  "DELETE FROM Users",
                  [],
                  () => {
                      navigation.navigate('Login')
                  },
                  error => { console.log(error) }
              )
          })

      } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
      }
  }

  **object to store function, fired when touchable is clicked
  bound to touchable opacity onPress**

  const handleNotification = (item) => {
      PushNotification.localNotification({
          title: 'Push Notification',
          message: 'You clicked on' + item.country
      })
  }

  return(
      <View style={styles.body}>
          <Text style={[
              GlobalStyle.header,
              GlobalStyle.text
          ]}>
              Welcome {name} !
          </Text>

          **flatlist used to display api fetch responses
          push notification onPress function is bound to TouchableOpacity object**

          <FlatList
              data={cities}
              renderItem={({item}) => (
                  <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={() => { handleNotification(item) }}
                  >
                      <View style={styles.item}>
                          <Text style={styles.title}>{item.country}</Text>
                          <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{item.city}</Text>
                      </View>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          />
      </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  body: {
    flex: 1,
    // justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  // now obsolete, as we have replaced this with a global style
  text: {
    // fontWeight: 'bold',
    // fontSize: 26,
    margin: 10,
    // fontFamily: 'TitilliumWeb-Bold'
  },
  navButton: {
    borderRadius: 11,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    width: 180,
    height: 50,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  openDrawerButton: {
    borderRadius: 11,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    width: 180,
    height: 50,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 10
  },
  thirdFont: {
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingTop: 20,
    fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular'
  },
  textInput: {
    width: 250,
    height: 50,
    marginTop: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#d9cbe7',
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderColor: '#d9c1c1',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 20
  },
  item: {
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      borderWidth: 3,
      borderColor: '#bfcab8',
      borderRadius: 7,
      margin: 7,
      width: 350,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      paddingVertical: 10
  },
    title: {
      fontSize: 20,
      fontFamily: 'Ubuntu-Bold',
      color: '#a03f3f'
    },
    subtitle: {
      marginTop: 8,
      fontFamily: 'Ubuntu-Regular',
      fontSize: 16
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import PushNotificationIOS from "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios";

export default class NotifService {

  constructor(onRegister, onNotification) {
    this.configure(onRegister, onNotification);

    this.lastId = 0;
  }

  configure(onRegister, onNotification, gcm = "") {
    PushNotificationIOS.configure({
      // (optional) Called when Token is generated (iOS and Android)
      onRegister: onRegister, //this._onRegister.bind(this),

      // (required) Called when a remote or local notification is opened or received
      onNotification: onNotification, //this._onNotification,

      // ANDROID ONLY: GCM Sender ID (optional - not required for local notifications, but is need to receive remote push notifications)
      senderID: gcm,

      // IOS ONLY (optional): default: all - Permissions to register.
      permissions: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true
      },

      // Should the initial notification be popped automatically
      // default: true
      popInitialNotification: true,

      /**
        * (optional) default: true
        * - Specified if permissions (ios) and token (android and ios) will requested or not,
        * - if not, you must call PushNotificationsHandler.requestPermissions() later
        */
      requestPermissions: true,
    });
  }

  localNotif(title, message, sound, color) {
    this.lastId++;
    PushNotificationIOS.localNotificationSchedule({
      /* Android Only Properties */
      id: ''+this.lastId, // (optional) Valid unique 32 bit integer specified as string. default: Autogenerated Unique ID
      ticker: "My Notification Ticker", // (optional)
      autoCancel: true, // (optional) default: true
      largeIcon: "ic_launcher", // (optional) default: "ic_launcher"
      smallIcon: "ic_notification", // (optional) default: "ic_notification" with fallback for "ic_launcher"
      bigText: message, // (optional) default: "message" prop
      color: color, // (optional) default: system default
      vibrate: true, // (optional) default: true
      vibration: 300, // vibration length in milliseconds, ignored if vibrate=false, default: 1000
      tag: 'some_tag', // (optional) add tag to message
      group: "group", // (optional) add group to message
      ongoing: false, // (optional) set whether this is an "ongoing" notification

      /* iOS only properties */
      alertAction: 'view', // (optional) default: view
      category: '', // (optional) default: null
      userInfo: {}, // (optional) default: null (object containing additional notification data)

      /* iOS and Android properties */
      title: title, // (optional)
      message: message, // (required)
      playSound: sound, // (optional) default: true
      soundName: 'default', // (optional) Sound to play when the notification is shown. Value of 'default' plays the default sound. It can be set to a custom sound such as 'android.resource://com.xyz/raw/my_sound'. It will look for the 'my_sound' audio file in 'res/raw' directory and play it. default: 'default' (default sound is played)
      actions: '["Yes", "No"]',  // (Android only) See the doc for notification actions to know more
    });
  }

  checkPermission(cbk) {
    return PushNotification.checkPermissions(cbk);
  }

  cancelNotif() {
    console.log(this.lastId, "***")
    PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({id: ''+this.lastId});
  }

  cancelAll() {
    PushNotification.cancelAllLocalNotifications();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shivo'ham 0. Tried that, doesn't seem to have worked. I now have a build error with the following message 'React/RCTPushNotificationManager.h' file not found
#import <React/RCTPushNotificationManager.h>

Comment: Add this to the Podfile
pod 'React-RCTPushNotification', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/PushNotificationIOS'